# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric - Can't find answer that fits

Tags: sql-server-2008

Been searching for an hour and can't find an answer that addresses what's happening with my code. This query happily returns data:

```
WITH RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT_CTE(RequisitionNumber, ResultsName, ResultValue)
AS
(
SELECT [RequisitionNumber]
      ,[ResultsName]
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM([ResultValue]))
FROM dbo.RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT
--WHERE TestGroupNumber IN ('T4367', 'T8033')
WHERE SUBSTRING(RequisitionNumber, 2, 4) = '1521'
AND ResultsName = 'HEMOGLOBIN A1C'
AND ISNUMERIC(ResultValue) = 1
)
, RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT_CTE2(RequisitionNumber, ResultsName, ResultValue)
AS
(
SELECT RequisitionNumber
      ,ResultsName
      ,CAST(ResultValue AS decimal(3,1)) AS ResultValue
FROM RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT_CTE
)
SELECT * FROM RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT_CTE2
```

Here are the first few rows of data, just as expected:

```
RequisitionNumber   ResultsName     ResultValue
C1521020510         HEMOGLOBIN A1C  5.9
C1521044250         HEMOGLOBIN A1C  5.4
C1521123010         HEMOGLOBIN A1C  5.6
C1521121420         HEMOGLOBIN A1C  5.8
C1521102210         HEMOGLOBIN A1C  13.2
```

However, when I change the last line to this, it throws an "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric." error:

```
SELECT * FROM RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT_CTE2 
WHERE CAST(ResultValue AS decimal(3,1)) BETWEEN 7.5 AND 10
```

I also get the error if I leave out the "CAST" and just put `WHERE ResultValue BETWEEN 7.5 AND 10`. I have confirmed that all the data in the ResultValue column is numeric in the format 00.0. I need that WHERE clause to fulfill the requirement that the value be >=7.5 and <=10. I expected it to return that last row where ResultValue is 13.2, but instead I get that error. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

(I also get the error if I use just the first CTE.)

Comment: what if you try ' BETWEEN CAST(7.5 AS decimal(3,1)) AND CAST(10 AS decimal(3,1)) ' instead of BETWEEN 7.5 AND 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here, the first is that just because something passes as `ISNUMERIC` does not mean you can convert it to a decimal. The following will return 1:

```
SELECT  ISNUMERIC('1,0');
```

But this will return an error:

```
SELECT CAST('1,0' AS DECIMAL(3, 1))
```

The other, less obvious problem is that you have no control over when SQL Server will perform which operation, so even though you have `ISNUMERIC(resultValue) = 1` in the first CTE, there is no guarantee that this will be executed before `WHERE CAST(ResultValue AS decimal(3,1)) BETWEEN 7.5 AND 10`. So you could still be trying (and failing) to cast non numeric values to a decimal. It works when it is in the `SELECT` because this is evaluated after the `WHERE`.

There are two ways around this, the latter is a hack. The preferable way around it is to force the materialisation of the first query by using a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #ResultsComponent
(
    [RequisitionNumber] VARCHAR(50),
    [ResultsName] VARCHAR(50),
    ResultValue DECIMAL(3, 1)
);
INSERT #ResultsComponent (RequisitionNumber, ResultsName, ResultValue)
SELECT [RequisitionNumber]
      ,[ResultsName]
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM([ResultValue]))
FROM dbo.RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT
--WHERE TestGroupNumber IN ('T4367', 'T8033')
WHERE SUBSTRING(RequisitionNumber, 2, 4) = '1521'
AND ResultsName = 'HEMOGLOBIN A1C'
AND ISNUMERIC(ResultValue) = 1;

SELECT  RequisitionNumber, ResultsName, ResultValue
FROM    #ResultsComponent
WHERE   ResultValue BETWEEN 7.5 AND 10;
```

The other way, which is a hack, and not guaranteed to work is to use `TOP` to force the order of execution, but ensure you choose a value high enough that it doesn't affect the results:

```
WITH RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT_CTE(RequisitionNumber, ResultsName, ResultValue)
AS
(
SELECT TOP (100000)
        [RequisitionNumber]
      ,[ResultsName]
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM([ResultValue]))
FROM dbo.RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT
--WHERE TestGroupNumber IN ('T4367', 'T8033')
WHERE SUBSTRING(RequisitionNumber, 2, 4) = '1521'
AND ResultsName = 'HEMOGLOBIN A1C'
AND ISNUMERIC(ResultValue) = 1
)
SELECT RequisitionNumber
      ,ResultsName
      ,CAST(ResultValue AS decimal(3,1)) AS ResultValue
FROM RESULTS_TEST_COMPONENT_CTE
WHERE CAST(ResultValue AS decimal(3,1)) BETWEEN 7.5 AND 10;
```

We can recreate the problem fairly simply:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ResultValue VARCHAR(100))
INSERT #T (ResultValue)
SELECT  t.ResultValue
FROM    sys.all_objects o
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(100))), (CAST(object_id AS VARCHAR(100)))) t (ResultValue);

WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ResultValue = CAST(ResultValue AS INT)
    FROM    #T
    WHERE   ISNUMERIC(ResultValue) = 1
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE 
WHERE   ResultValue BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

And then view the estimated plan (can't get actual plan due to error) and see that both predicates (`ISNUMERIC` and `BETWEEN 1 AND 10`) are evaluated at the same time:

[image]

By adding top we can change the plan, so that the initial table scan filters for `ISNUMERIC` and then uses an additional step to ensure `BETWEEN 1 AND 10` is applied only to numeric data:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  TOP (1000000) ResultValue = CAST(ResultValue AS INT)
    FROM    #T
    WHERE   ISNUMERIC(ResultValue) = 1
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE 
WHERE   ResultValue BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gareth, I was wondering if using a temp table rather than a CTE would work and was going to try it. What I discovered was that using "ResultValue >= 7.5 AND ResultValue <= 10" instead of the BETWEEN function worked. Not sure why.  I may change it to a temp table anyway to be safe.